# Jforum : Show customize exception message to user

Tags: java, jsp, exception

I am using jforum2 but it show error like that

```
An error has occurred.

For detailed error information, please see the HTML source code, and contact the forum Administrator.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,989,022 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 6 milliseconds ago.

Query being executed when exception was thrown:
SELECT COUNT(pm.privmsgs_to_userid) AS private_messages, u.* FROM jforum_users u LEFT JOIN jforum_privmsgs pm ON pm.privmsgs_type = 1 AND pm.privmsgs_to_userid = u.user_id WHERE u.user_id = 1 GROUP BY pm.privmsgs_to_userid
```

While i will want to show customize error message to user what and where i have to make change to show customize error message rather than above message to forum user ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-throwing the `Exception` you might want to catch it and use the message as you like.